# expression for "show mock surprise"

Tags: phrase-request, expressions, idiom-request

Is there a verbal expression or idiom that means "to show mock surprise," particularly by touching a part of one's body?

Comment: In what way does "touching a part of one's body" relate to "pretending to be surprised"?

Comment: Cf. "clutch the/one's pearls."

Comment: I don't understand that either! Well, actually, I've just looked it up. But a necklace isn't a body part. People slap their forehead to indicate ***surprise at their own foolishness*** (or affectation thereof), but I've never heard of that necklace version.

Comment: clutch one's pearls means something other than mock surprise. It is a sarcastic phrase used to characterize what someone says or does.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Have you seen any pictures illustrating the said idiom? No real pearls or necklaces, but body parts, are involved in the action.

Comment: There's a (frequently affected) gesture stereotypically associated with pre-war middle-class middle-aged women raising an arm/hand to their chest as if to signify "I'm so shocked I'm having a heart attack!". I suppose that's what you're getting at. See [these written instances](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22clutching+her+chest+in%22+-%22her+chest+in+pain%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03XeiO7IJlJYan7ow6jxD2OB2RMMg:1616673922375&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqjPHWs8vvAhUGIsAKHVJpBa8QpwUIJg&biw=1512&bih=691&dpr=1.25) of ***clutching her chest** in [real or affected fright/surprise]*.

Comment: How about _facepalm_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facepalm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that there is a phrase that demonstrates mock surprise. Surprise is often shown with raised eyebrows. For example, you can say something "raised eyebrows" or someone "raised their eyebrows in surprise". Another physical action is covering your mouth but that is clearer when followed by "...in surprise". You're better off describing a comical overexertion or saying "...in mock surprise".